# What is the appropriate way to input the data of working hours?

Tags: dataset

In my dataset, `working hours` is weekly working hours. If the person's employed, then working hours > 0. However, I'm not quite sure how to input the data for working hours if the person is not employed. Do I input it as "NA", or 0?

In addition, I'm trying to do a logarithm transformation on the data of working hours. If I were to input data as 0 for the unemployed, how should I do the log transformation? Should I keep it as 0, or leave it as NA?

Thanks!

Comment: Depending on the goal, either could be useful. What problem are you trying to solve & how does collecting this data help you solve the problem?

Comment: @Sycorax I'm trying to determine the effect of an individual being a grandparent on working hours.

Comment: Regarding the logarithm transformation, why do you want to do it?

Comment: It's conceivable, even likely, that some employed people occasionally work zero hours in a week (such as during vacations or when sick). Thus it's a good idea to differentiate zero hours from being unemployed when you enter data.  How to *model* that difference is a a separate matter.  Applying the log to data that can have zeros is not a great idea, as you already can tell.  You will find it most constructive to back up and try to answer the questions @Sycorax asked in the initial comment.

Comment: @whuber Good point. But in my dataset, if the person is employed, then working hours > 0. I guess it's a sampling problem. And please see my above comment for my research question :)

Comment: @Dave See the percentage change in working hours.

Comment: It would still be dangerous to assume that being employed implies positive working hours continues in the future.  It's unclear how that is any kind of "sampling problem," though.  We now seem to have *three* different issues in play: (1) recording data; (2) sampling a process; (3) transforming data for some purpose.  This threatens to grow unfocused and unanswerable, so please consider carefully what you really need to ask.

Comment: @whuber This is readily available survey data. The surveyed individuals literally have positive working hours if the individual is employed. I just want to know whether being a grandparent decreases working hours.

Comment: And *there* is a fourth question!  It raises many issues.  For instance, unless this is a longitudinal survey, it's unlikely it can answer your question at all.  Note, too, that the possibility of taking logarithms is related to *how you measure average working hours,* because a decrease in the average log hours is not the same as a decrease in the average hours.  Indeed, in rare circumstances one of those averages could be higher among grandparents while the other average is actually lower among grandparents.

Comment: @whuber This is a longitudinal survey. And yes, I know, a decrease in the average log hours is not the same as a decrease in the average hours. I want to know the percentage decrease. There is a paper that did this: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0014292121001598